# How can I trace code execution in Clojure?

Tags: debugging, clojure

Why learning Clojure, I sometimes need to see what a function does at each step. For example:

```
(defn kadane [coll]
   (let [pos+ (fn [sum x] (if (neg? sum) x (+ sum x)))
         ending-heres (reductions pos+ 0 coll)]
     (reduce max ending-heres)))
```

Should I insert `println` here and there (where, how); or is there a suggested workflow/tool?

Comment: Incidentally, automatically tracing -- and marking up Clojure code with values of its variables at runtime -- is one of the things the [Light Table editor](http://lighttable.com/), for all its broken promises, brings to the table.

Comment: I just start IntelliJ's debugger and place breakpoints. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may not be what you're after at the level of a single function (see Charles Duffy's comment below), but if you wanted to do get an overview of what's going on at the level of a namespace (or several), you could use [tools.trace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace) (disclosure: I'm a contributor):

```
(ns foo.core)

(defn foo [x] x)
(defn bar [x] (foo x))

(in-ns 'user) ; standard REPL namespace

(require '[clojure.tools.trace :as trace])
(trace/trace-ns 'foo.core)

(foo.core/bar 123)
TRACE t20387: (foo.core/bar 123)
TRACE t20388: | (foo.core/foo 123)
TRACE t20388: | => 123
TRACE t20387: => 123
```

It won't catch inner functions and such (as pointed out by Charles), and might be overwhelming with large code graphs, but when exploring small-ish code graphs it can be quite convenient.

(It's also possible to trace individually selected Vars if the groups of interest aren't perfectly aligned with namespaces.)

Comment: I would have suggested this myself, but as I read this, the OP is trying to see inside a single function call, no?

Comment: ("inside a single function call" meaning not just its arguments and return values, but those of anonymous functions it contains).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh indeed, I think you're right. +1 to Sayid then. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you use Emacs with CIDER as most Clojurians do, you already have a built-in debugger:

https://docs.cider.mx/cider/debugging/debugger.html

Chances are your favorite IDE/Editor has something built-in or a plugin already.

There is also (in no particular order):

- [spyscope](https://github.com/dgrnbrg/spyscope)
- [timbre](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre)/spy
- [tupelo](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging)/spyx
- [sayid](https://github.com/bpiel/sayid)
- [tools.trace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace)
- good old `println`

I would look at the above first. However there were/are other possibilities:

- https://gist.github.com/ato/252421
- https://github.com/philoskim/debux
- https://github.com/pallet/ritz/tree/develop/nrepl-core
- https://github.com/hozumi/eyewrap
- probably many more

Also, if the function is simple enough you can add `def`s at development-time to peek inside the bindings at a given time inside your function.

Answer (score 6):

[Sayid](https://github.com/bpiel/sayid) is a tool presented at Clojure Conj 2016 that's directly appropriate to the purpose and comes with an excellent Emacs plugin. See [the talk at which it was presented](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipDhvd1NsmE).

To see inside invocations of transient functions, see [`ws-add-inner-trace-fn`](https://github.com/bpiel/sayid/blob/2fe67b85cfbc4d6a351348b746564899bc7a2d81/src/com/billpiel/sayid/core.clj#L132) (previously, `ws-add-deep-trace-fn`).

Comment: Author of sayid here. I just wanted to leave a note to encourage anyone trying sayid to get in touch (github issues, email, twitter) with any questions or problems they run into. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I frequently use the `spyx` and related functions like `spy-let` from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging) for this purpose:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn kadane [coll]
   (spy-let [ pos+ (fn [sum x] (if (neg? sum) x (+ sum x)))
              ending-heres (reductions pos+ 0 coll) ]
     (spyx (reduce max ending-heres))))
(spyx (kadane (range 5)))
```

will produce output:

```
pos+ => #object[tst.clj.core$kadane$pos_PLUS___21786 0x3e7de165 ...]
ending-heres => (0 0 1 3 6 10)
(reduce max ending-heres) => 10
(kadane (range 5)) => 10
```

IMHO it is hard to beat a simple `println` or similar for debugging. Log files are also invaluable as you get closer to production.